# LIKE command Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this like command? I get an error. I use c# and mysql database.

```
 public static DataSet getInstructorListSearchEmail(string instemail)
        {
            DB.connectToDb();
            DB.DBOpen();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            string comText = "select * from instructor where Instructor_email like %instemail";
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(comText, DB.Conn);
            com.Parameters.Add("instemail", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = instemail;
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: You might be so kind and tell us the exception

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%instemail' at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing now you used a cmd parameter you need to modify your query string to accept parameters by changing it to something like

```
string comText = "select * from instructor where Instructor_email like @instemail";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instemail", "%" + instemail);
```

or this would work as well using single quotes and drop the parameter but I think using parameters are better.

```
string comText = "select * from instructor where Instructor_email like '%" + instemail + "'";
```

Comment: The last example is very bad; it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the wildcard directly to your parameter value and not in the sql command text before the parameter placeholder (Try to use the parameter prefix by the way)

```
  string comText = "select * from instructor where Instructor_email like @instemail";
```

so your command parameter should be

```
  com.Parameters.Add("@instemail", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = "%" + instemail;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use single quotes like;

```
string comText = "select * from instructor where Instructor_email like @instemail";
```