# Search Database for rows, whose Column contains a specific string [Search-Query]

Tags: c#, mysql

I was wondering why this SQL Query doesn't return anything:

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE Username LIKE %@Username% ORDER BY Id DESC";
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", this.search.Text);
```

IT's not a reader problem or anything like this, if i remove "WHERE Username LIKE %@Username% ", it works fine.
I call this whole MySQL-Query in a KeyPress-Event of a Textbox.
this.search is the Textbox. I want to search for rows where the Username Column contains the Characters i entered in the Textbox.

Comment: if you're looking for a specific string, use `=` and not LIKE

Comment: Plus, `LIKE %@Username%` seeing that's a string, you need to treat it as one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i want to check if the Username-Column contains a string, = is not what i need for that

Comment: first question is why are you using inline SQL in your C# rather than a Stored Procedure.   Next are you looking for a specific string in a bigger string, or the exact match at all times?

Comment: This Q&A may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/16374840/1415724

Comment: @SimonPrice Havn't really dealt with Stored Procedures yet, i've always used inline SQL and i'm looking for something like a string.Contains()-Method, so it returns the row, if the text is equal but also if only "Ba" is given and the column string is "Bae"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
//For LIKE query
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@query", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
parameter.Value = string.Format("%{0}%", this.search.Text);
IList<Users> results = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Users>("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE @query", parameter).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using @query without any quotes? It has worked for me for more than an year now, reverify the SqlDbType if you are not using NVarChar

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this with MySQL, since some of those variables are never declared, so i tried to modify it for my needs, but it didn't work

Comment: Yeah that's true but those variables are not related or matter in this context. By the way, these variables are just the references for DbContext object (entity framework) so you can ignore these..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this:

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE Username LIKE @Username ORDER BY Id DESC";
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", "%" + this.search.Text + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using a stored procedure, will help against SQL Injection attacks, and you want to disallow your app to use insert, update and delete scripts and only allow it to use execute statements for stored procedures.

But you want to change this line from

`mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM`users`WHERE Username LIKE %@Username% ORDER BY Id DESC";`

to

`mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM`users`WHERE Username LIKE '%@Username%' ORDER BY Id DESC";`