# C# MariaDB Exception

Tags: c#, mariadb

I have some code and when it executes, it throws a MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException saying,

What does this mean, and what can I do about it?
Depending on classes used it can also be MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'a'%' at line 1

```
public void searchProduct(DataGridView data, TextBox searchString)
{
    connection.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select id, productName, productType, productQuantity, productPurchasePrice, productPurchaseDate, productSalePrice, productTax from products where productName like = @name%", connection);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", searchString.Text);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    data.DataSource = dt;
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question to be in line with the guidance there. For instance, the section "Write a title that summarizes the problem" specifically notes that the title should be more specific than some tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LIKE command Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374840/like-command-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

The bind variable name is `@name`. You can't just add characters to it, you'll have to explicitly concatenate them. E.g.:

**EDIT:**
You also need to remove the `=` after the `like`, which I missed originally. See the edited query:

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select id, productName, productType, productQuantity, productPurchasePrice, productPurchaseDate, productSalePrice, productTax from products where productName like CONCAT(@name, '%')", connection);
-- Here -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. Thank you for taking care of me.

Comment: @KamilMERT I missed the `=` there, see my edited answer

Comment: Thank You @Mureinik I changed your method a little bit and it worked.